# Windows anti-virus off Linux server

Tags: linux, anti-virus

We have a customer trying to replace all Windows Servers with Linux. Problem he has only Windows clients. We are able to migrate most of the server apps. But the antivirus suites he has and all alternative we can think off needs Windows Server. Is there a way to run multi user Antivirus suites for the network to run off a Linux Server, ie the clients need to access the server

Answer (score 1):

Might want to look at a cloud antivirus solution. [McAfee](http://www.mcafeesaas.com) offers one. [Trend Micro](http://us.trendmicro.com/us/products/sb/worry-free-business-security-hosted/) also offers one. I'm sure there are many many more. I'm not sure of any AVs that run their console on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for email then you can use [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/)

Comment: -1, He's looking for a Client AV Management suite that runs Windows Clients from a Linux Server.

Comment: You can use ClamAV to scan emails. I don't think there's currently any type of client-scanning AV that runs off a Linux server, you'd need access to the filesystem on that Windows machine, if that was the case.

Answer (score 1):

You've not said what the servers/clients actually do. Most commonly, this kind of setup uses SMB type file-serving. While there are lots of AV software available for Linux, you probably need something which integrates with the file serving software (most likely Samba) if you want on-access scanning.

Have a look at samba-vscan and clamuko. Both these provide integration between samba and various AV scanning engines.

Note that as others have mentioned, clamav is a free virus scanning package. IME, it can be a little slower than some of the commercial engines, but is at least as good, and in some cases better at indetifying viruses and not flagging false positives (jag7720 - I've found sophos has a rather high false positive rate). It's perhaps weaker than some products for repairing files - but these are all very much moving targets.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's looking for a Client AV Management suite that runs Windows Clients from a Linux Server, not just AV for the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run the antivirus admin interface into [wine](http://www.winehq.org/), but this implies the installation of a graphical environment (KDE, GNOME, etc) on your linux server.

The last option is maintain only one windows server for antivirus suite.

Comment: That I am afraid is not an option. We cant have GUI on servers

Comment: @ramdaz: this is Unix - you can have the windows rendered on the clients.

Comment: While this might actually work, it's an ugly hack at best.

Answer (score -1):

If the person purchased say licenses for Symantec SEP suite then on the SEP Disc 2(I think) is an installer for Linux based systems . Poke around his current suite of products and see what you find.